# How to find the size of a file and assign it to a variable in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting

I am writing a Unix script that reads the size of a text file and if the file is of some size it should print the text file. If it is not an *else*, a loop executes and the process continues.

I am using the following command to find the size of that text file.

```
ls -l ${filepath}/{filename}.lst | awk '{print $5}'
```

How do I assign it to a variable inside the script and put it in an if condition? Or, for example, does the *if* condition `if[$var==461]` work?

or is there another command I can use to find the size of the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) command which eliminates the need to use [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK).

For example, in Linux with Bash where *myfile* is your file path:

```
sz=$(stat -c '%s' myfile)
if [ $sz -eq 100 ]; then
    echo "myfile is 100 bytes"
fi
```

Take **note** of the equality command `-eq` that's the arithmetic binary operator in Bash.

Alternatively, you can use a variable for the file path:

```
f=my/file/path
sz=$(stat -c '%s' $f)
if [ $sz -eq 100 ]; then
    echo "$f is 100 bytes"
fi
```

Comment: `$sz` rather than `myfile`

Comment: will i be able to specify the path of the file there like
sz=$(stat -c '%s' filepath/myfile)

Comment: @AbdulAshikKhanM if not, then the alternative is that the posted solution requires your file to be named `myfile` and exist in the directory you run the command from.

Comment: @AbdulAshikKhanM yes you will be able to specify your own file name (path).

Comment: Needs more quotes. `stat -c '%s' "$f"`, or filenames with spaces will be split into multiple arguments to `stat`. Likewise, safer to use `[ "$sz" -eq 100 ]` rather than `[ $sz -eq 100 ]` such as to get a better error message from test should `stat` fail (or more reliable behavior in other corner cases, such as digits present inside the numeric value being present in IFS).

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) which is not portable, not being specified by POSIX.

Here is a safer way to get the file size in a variable.

```
size=$(ls -dnL -- "${filepath}/{filename}.lst" | awk '{print $5;exit}')
```

Comment: Ugh. If `stat(1)` is not available, I would rather prefer using perl or something similar over parsing `ls -l` output.

Comment: @user2719058 If `stat` is not available, the odds that `perl` is neither do exist. Neither `stat` nor `perl` are specified by POSIX and the question is tagged `unix`, that's the reason why I stick with standard tools and options. While I agree parsing `ls` output is generally a bad idea, I believe I took enough precautions to avoid any risk in that specific case.

Comment: @jlliagre, not sure I agree re: the first line there -- as distasteful as I find it, if one excludes embedded systems perl is considerably more widespread than GNU stat: it's been around on commercial UNIXes for decades, after all (whereas non-GNU implementations of `stat` are still common today).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I' didn't wrote the odds are high, just they do exist. My point was more about sticking to `POSIX` tools. Neither `stat` nor `perl` are.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your file size in a variable and then check equality with -eq

```
size=`ls -l ${filepath}/{filename}.lst| awk '{print $5}'`
if [ $size  -eq 461 ]
then
   echo "MATCHED"
else
  echo "NOT MATCHED"
fi
```

Comment: No, don't parse the output of `ls`. Use `stat` instead.

Comment: ...or if one *must* parse `ls`, one should be suitably paranoid about it, as the answer by @jlliagre is (handling filenames that start with dashes, filenames with literal newlines combined with `ls` implementations that fail to escape them, and other corner cases) and this answer is not.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it as-

```
var=$(ls -l ${filepath}/{filename}.lst | awk '{print $5}')
```