# getting file size from the ls output

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a variable named `$lsoutput` in which I store the result of the `ls -l` command
It's content is

- -rw-r--r-- 1 root ftp 44 Apr 29 2003 `first_file.txt`
- I would like to get the size of that file.
- I useed the following regular expression

---

```
if [[ "$lsoutput" =~ ^[-rwx]{10}[[:space:]][[:digit:]]+[[:space:]][[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]][[:alnum:]]+[[:space]]([[:digit:]]+) ]]
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Unfortuantely this regexp does not work. What is wrong with it? Can you provide a correct one? Thanks for your help

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- particularly the section titled "Getting Metadata From A File"

Comment: Consider `size=$(wc -c <first_file.txt)` -- portable, robust, and (with a version of `wc` that uses `stat` data when given a real file handle) fast.

Comment: Related: [Portable way to get file size in bytes in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815329/portable-way-to-get-file-size-in-bytes-in-shell)

Comment: (To be clear, I didn't add the above "related" link to the duplicate list because the primary duplicate asks about the `ls` approach *in the question itself*, and has [at least one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25466100/14122) describing how to use `ls` for the purpose in a way that avoids some of the more common failure modes).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it easier to use:

`ls -l | awk '{print $5}'`

Which just prints the file size?

Comment: Missing closing apostrophe, also the `-rt` options are not necessary for this to work. Anyway much cleaner than using that long regexp here, specially if it is wrong.

Comment: SO does not let me edit the answer as it needs at least 6 chars to edit, and did not want to just make some rewording, this is your answer... so please edit it.

Comment: Fixed with your comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's much easier way.

```
stat --format=%s <FILE>
```

The above command prints the size of the file in bytes.

Parsing `ls` output [is not recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: One can also use GNU find: `find "$file" -maxdepth 0 -printf '%s\n'`, for instance.

Comment: Or `stat -f %z <FILE>` on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

with cut:

```
ls -l|tr -s ' ' |cut -d' ' -f5
```